# Erro no Apache2 no linux

Tags: mysql, linux, apache

Galera instalei tudo certinho no Linux, joguei minha pasta no diretório `www` quando abri no broswer recebi o seguinte aviso:

> Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: NO)

Como resolvo?

Comment: Isso ta parecendo erro de acesso ao mysql, verifique no seu arquivo de conexão se você não está passando senha junto com usuario. É recomendavel você adicionar uma senha, mesmo que seja somente em ambiente local.

Comment: Tentei redefinir uma senha agora no mysql mais só recebo o mesmo erro  `1045`

Comment: Verifique se a porta do mysql está aberta (nmap localhost). Vê se ajuda: http://askubuntu.com/a/272435/436114

Comment: Você pode postar o código que você está usando na conexão com o banco?

Answer (score 1):

No `mysql_connect` você está passando uma senha para se conectar ao banco em `localhost`.

Porém o usuário `root` não possui senha. Então é só remover a senha que você está passando e tentar novamente.

```
mysql_connect ('localhost','root','');
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Isso não é problema com o Apache2, e sim de conexão com o MySQL.

2) Você está tentando acessar o MySQL com o usuário root em localhost *sem utilizar uma senha* `(using password: NO)`, porém o root deve estar com uma (é o contrário do que o **rubStackOverflow** disse).

3) Se possível, evite usar as funções mysql_* do PHP pois ela são obsoletas e não funcionam mais no PHP 7.0. Dê preferência ao [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode [redefinir sua senha de root](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset). Tenha em mente que não é aconselhável a utilização de root sem senha. Logo depois você tem que reiniciar o serviço para que as alterações funcione corretamente usando:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```